# How to load and update changing data using SQOOP?

Tags: apache, sqoop, sqoop2

I tried with **increment import** but I have to specify either **append** or **lastmodified**.  I need all changes, both modified and new records.

Comment: Shortened title; corrected run-on sentences in description.

Answer (score 1):

Your understading is partially correct here.

As per the [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports),

> An alternate table update strategy supported by Sqoop is called lastmodified mode. You should use this when rows of the source table may be updated, and each such update will set the value of a last-modified column to the current timestamp. **Rows where the check column holds a timestamp more recent than the timestamp specified with --last-value are imported**.

(*Emphasis is mine*)

Now lets try  to understand this using an example,

I have a table `employees` having `name`, `salary` and `updated_on` fields. Sample record:

```
name |salary | updated_on

dev  | 2000  | 2016-01-01
```

Now salary of the some of the employees has changed in the next month and some new employee joined in that month.

Now in your Sqoop Import command, you will specify `--check-column updated_on`, `--incremental lastmodified` and `--last-value "2016-01-01"`.

**All the records added or updated after this `--last-value` will be imported.**

Comment: Thanks for great response.it helps a lot. Thanks